# Google Action Alpha Release : Going Mad with just a simple release

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

I have created a chatbot using Dialogflow for which I created an alpha release on google actions.The status of the release is deployed. I have added around 9 whitelisted members and shared the opt-in link with them.

But when they open the opt-in link on their google assistant, it says "I could not find it".

I have gone through all the possible articles or issues created till date. I have done all the things necessary like waited for 24 hours instead of just 3 hours. Given all the permission on google assistant. I am not able to find the solutions. Please help, i am getting mad with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link needs to be specifically opened on a mobile device (Android or iOS) and not opened "on their google assistant". This should bring them to the appropriate page on Explore with a section inviting them into the Alpha channel. Make sure the email address on the approved list is the same email address they are using for their account.

Comment: Thanks it worked, actually when i was clicking on the opt-in link it was by default opening it in Google Assistant, that s where the problem was. What i did is copy the link and past in chrome browser in mobile device. It asked me for the agreement and thats it. Thanks buddy.